# Constructing new $a$-$b$ separators from old.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a (finite) connected (simple) graph of order $|G|>2$ and distinct vertices $a,b \in V(G)$ with $X,X' \subsetneq V(G)\setminus \{a,b\}$ as $a$-$b$ separators in $G$.

Moreover, let $C_a, C_b$ be the components of $G-X$, and $C_a', C_b'$ the components of $G-X'$ with $A := V(C_a) \ni a \in V(C_a') =: A'$ and $B := V(C_b) \ni b \in V(C_b') =: B'$.

Define $Y_a := (X \cap A') \cup (X \cap X') \cup (X' \cap A)$ 
and $Y_b := (X \cap B') \cup (X \cap X') \cup (X' \cap B)$.

I know that $Y_a$ and $Y_b$ are again $a$-$b$ separators. 
Furthermore, if $|X|$ and $|X'|$ are minimal, then $|Y_a|$ and $|Y_b|$ are also minimal.

My question is this: 
If $X$ and $X'$ are minimal (with respect to $\subseteq$) as $a$-$b$ separators, need $Y_a$ and $Y_b$ also be minimal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Counterexample]

If $X$ and $X'$ are minimal $a$-$b$ separators, then $Y_a$ and $Y_b$ need **not** be minimal (in general).
See the figure above as a counter-example.
Note that $Z$ **is** a minimal $a$-$b$ separator.